# Django rest framework bulk: Correct URL syntax for bulk operations?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting to carry out bulk DELETEs/PUTs on my Django API, `mymodel` inherits from `MultipleDBModelViewSet` which in turn inherits from the [`BulkModelViewSet`](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk)

The bulk destroy method is as follows

```py
class MultipleDBModelViewSet(BulkModelViewSet):
    ...
    ...
    def bulk_destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ids = json.loads(request.query_params.get("ids"))
        if not ids:
            return super().destroy(request, *args, pk=kwargs.pop("pk"), **kwargs)
        else:
            return super().bulk_destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In my `urls.py` file I define the URL used to interact with my model:

```py
router.register(r"v1/mymodels", mymodels_views_v1.MyModelViewSet)
```

this allows me to GET, POST, PUT and DELETE on the URL (works perfectly at present):

`www.my-api.com/v1/mymodels/{{mymodel_id}}`

Can I use this same URL for bulk operations? If so, what is the correct syntax?

eg: `www.my-api.com/v1/mymodels/?ids=[{{mymodel_id1}},{{mymodel_id2}}]`

If not, what changes should I make?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two things they are saying at their documentation.

1. Most API urls have two URL levels for each resource:

   ```
   url(r'foo/', ...)
   url(r'foo/(?P<pk>\d+)/', ...)
   ```

   The second url however is not applicable for bulk operations because
   the url directly maps to a single resource. Therefore all bulk
   generic views only apply to the first url.

That means it won't take url kwarg parameter.

2. The only exception to this is bulk delete. Consider a DELETE request
   to the first url. That can potentially delete all resources without
   any special confirmation. To try to account for this, bulk delete
   mixin allows to implement a hook to determine if the bulk delete
   request should be allowed:

```
class FooView(BulkDestroyAPIView):
    def allow_bulk_destroy(self, qs, filtered):
        # custom logic here
        # default checks if the qs was filtered
        # qs comes from self.get_queryset()
        # filtered comes from self.filter_queryset(qs)
        return qs is not filtered
```

**Solution:-**
You could do like this

```
class SimpleViewSet(generics.BulkModelViewSet):
    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        ids = self.request.query_params.get('ids')
        if ids:
            return queryset.filter(id__in=ids.split(',')
        # returns normal query set if no param
        return queryset
```

Comment: What does the `param` represent in the solution?

Comment: www.my-api.com/v1/mymodels/?ids=[{{mymodel_id1}},{{mymodel_id2}}]

'ids' is the query parameter(param) here

Comment: thanks, and where/how would `filter_queryset` be called?

Comment: It called at the DestroyMixin which is inherited by the viewset you are working, check line number 114 here https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/blob/master/rest_framework_bulk/drf2/mixins.py